# IBM SPSS QUESTION: Measure the perception of the respondents

Tags: spss, multiple-comparisons, sample-size

My problem to solve with IBM SPSS is: I have got answers to a question about X topic that contains 15 options of multiple response and I want to characterize the perception of the correspondents related to the X topic. Afterwards I have to compare the results accordingly to the genre of the respondents.

Is Compare Means with the Independent-Samples T Test the right approach?

Sorry if this isn't the right forum.

Thank you!

Comment: I would do something like a cluster analysis.

Comment: Thank you, will consider that as well! Have a good week!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<15 options of multiple response>

So, responders could choose multiple answers? Right?

If the answer is Yes, then you must do crosstabulations. If the answer is NO, then you must check your dependent variable for Normality using histograms and boxplots at least. Depending on the results, you may choose parametric testing such as t-tests or nonprametric testing such as Mann-whitney.

To choose the right test you must also know the levels of your independent variable. for example Gender (male/femal) has two levels which is suitable for t-testing.

sincerely,
Elias Estatistics